# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in c++ with 2d vector

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a puzzle solver using c++ for the first time. i've managed to create a sctruct named board with a 2d string vector and two interget repersenting the position of blank space.

However when i am assigning values to board i ran into this Segmentation fault (core dumped) and i dont know where i did wrong. If someone can pointed it out it would be much appreciate.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

struct Board
{
    vector<vector<string>> board;
    int blankx, blanky;
};

Board getBoard(string state)
{
    Board board;
    vector<vector<string>> matrix;
    int count = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 3; i++)
        {
            board.board [i][j] = state[count];
            if (state[count] == '#')
            {
                board.blankx = i;
                board.blanky = j;
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
    return board;
}

void findCost(string beginstate, string goalstate)
{
    int cost = 0;
    Board initBoard, finalBoard;
    initBoard = getBoard(beginstate);
    // printBoard(initBoard);

    cout << "the optimal cost is : " << cost << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    string beginState, goalState;

    cout << "please enter the begin state:\n";
    cin >> beginState;
    cout << "please enter the goal state:\n";
    cin >> goalState;

    findCost(beginState, goalState);
}
```

Comment: vectors are empty by default. without pushing or inserting elements, or pre-sizing a vector, any indexing you do will invoke *undefined behavior*. Unrelated, `matrix` is pointless in `getBoard`. It isn't used at all.

Comment: @WhozCraig thank i will try a different approach. matrix was used before i crated the Board struct i forgot to take it out.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct Board
{
    vector<vector<string>> board;
    int blankx, blanky;
};
```

When a `Board` gets created, its `board` member is a completely empty vector.

```
    Board board;

    // ...
            board.board [i][j] = state[count];
```

This creates a `Board`, then proceeds and ***assign*** values to its `board` std::vector.

That the `[]` operator for `std::vector`s does is that it accesses ***existing*** values in the vector. It does not ***create*** them. They must exist already. The vector must already be `resize()`d, or values must be `push_back()`ed into the vector so that `board.board[i][j]` is an ***existing*** value.

Because `board.board` is completely empty, and has no values at all, this becomes undefined behavior, and the reason for your crash.

Answer (score 1):

There are two critical bugs here:

1. The default initialized vector `board` is empty, try to access elements in it will cause the segment fault crash.

It can be fixed by initializing it:

```cpp
constexpr size_t kNum = 3;
struct Board {
  vector<vector<string>> board = {kNum, {kNum, string{}}};
  int blankx, blanky;
};
```

2. The index is mixed-used: the `i` in the second loop should be `j`, or we will get a crash even if the previous one is fixed. May fix as:

```cpp
  for (size_t i = 0; i < kNum; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < kNum; j++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, a `std::vector` is empty, and thus you are accessing the elements out-of-bounds.

The simplest solution, if you stay with using `vector`, is on construction, where you would initialize the `vector` appropriately sized:

```
struct Board
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> board;
    int blankx, blanky;

    // default constructor creates the board 
    Board() : board(3, std::vector<std::string>(3)) {}
};
```